# UIImagePickerController status bar issue in crop

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller, statusbar

I'm using `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance` and `preferredStatusBarStyle` to manage the status bar color and appearance.

My app lets the user choose a photo from his camera roll and crop it to square using the native crop option of `UIImagePickerController`.

So I push a `UIImagePickerController` and enable editing to get the crop screen.
The problem is, I want that for the albums and photos view, the status bar will be white, and for the crop view I want to hide the status bar.

how can I do that with `preferredStatusBarStyle` ?

until now I made a category for `UIImagePickerController` and implemented:

```
- (UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle {
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}
```

this indeed set the status bar to white color in photos, but when going to crop view, the status bar becomes black, that could be good for me because I want to hide it and the background is black so you can't see it, BUT the battery indicator is green! so you only see the battery indicator in the status bar!

how can I solve that? how can I hide the status bar only in the crop view?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to do a little bit of detective work here, but I can give you a lead.

I would suggest to subclass `UIImagePickerController` and return your statusbar preferences according to displayed child controller.

UIViewController has two methods that allow you to control statusbar visibility and appearance:

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden;
- (UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle
```

Simply override them, no `super` call needed.

You have access to view controllers stack within subclass so you can choose preferred style and visibility for statusbar according to number of controllers on stack.

I have a feeling that UIKit will ping `preferredStatusBarStyle` and `prefersStatusBarHidden` each time new child controller pushed on stack.

If not then you can force UIKit to update statusbar by calling:

```
[self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate]
```

Since `UIImagePickerController` is a subclass of `UINavigationController` you can assign your own delegate to it, monitor when new controller pushed on stack and call the suggested code above.

Comment: but my problem is that I don't know which controllers the UIImagePickerController is pushing, its all private. for example it can have in stack several view controllers: albums, photos and crop. and if I only wants to hide the status bar in the crop controller, how can I know?

Comment: Right, you can probably use `NSStringFromClass(self.topViewController.class)` to get a string name for a private class. This way you could identify controllers.

Comment: I think you'll find that a parent view controller's `prefersStatusBarHidden` isn't called again when a child is pushed, not unless `setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate` is used.

Comment: @smallduck looking at my answer today, I think you're totally right.

Answer (score 0):

Sort of a followup to [Andy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/351305/andy)'s post, yes subclassing `UIImagePickerController` used to be forbidden but is allowed now. There's some unexpected issues trying to override `prefersStatusBarHidden` and `preferredStatusBarStyle` though.

Note how `UIImagePickerController` is a subclass of `UINavigationController` and so itself is a container for child view controllers. How a container view controller controls status bar visibility and style to its children is by overriding `childViewControllerForStatusBarHidden` and `childViewControllerForStatusBarStyle`. In general `UINavigationController` doesn't implement those and usually one overrides them to return the currently visible view controller.

In a case like this though, where you don't control the child view controllers, your picker subclass can override these methods to return `nil`, and then your implementations of the `prefer` methods should take over. In theory, you then just have to make them return what you need at the right time, but as evidenced by my experience, there's something fishy going on with `UIImagePickerController` and the status bar style.

---

For my own `UIImagePickerController` subclass, I don't care about child view controllers given its custom UI, but I've experimented with returning `nil` from `childViewController..` and overriding the `prefer` methods. I've found that controlling the visibility to work fine, but something in the picker to counteract my subclass returning `LightContent` from `preferredStatusBarStyle`. See [my own question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27629714).