# UIImagePickerController vs status bar iOS8

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uikit, ios7-statusbar, uipickerviewcontroller

I'm subclassing `UIImagePickerController` in attempt to override its default status bar behavior and having mixed results. My app uses view controller-based status bar appearance.

---

Without subclassing, I'm finding that it changes the status bar style to `Default` (dark) when the picker is dismissed, and nothing I've tried yet in my initial view controller is fixing it. Also, when the picker hides the status bar while being presented, sliding it upwards, the initial view controller's navigation bar slides up with it from height 64 to 44.

So I want my `UIImagePickerController` subclass to keep the status bar style as `LightContent` and, in an attempt to work-around the sliding navigation bar, keep the status bar showing while presenting the picker, then hide it on `viewDidAppear:`.

The **first interesting thing** is that `preferredStatusBarStyle` and `prefersStatusBarHidden` in my picker subclass weren't called at all until I also overrode `childViewControllerForStatusBarStyle` and `childViewControllerForStatusBarHidden` to return nil. This seems to indicate that normally, a `UIImagePickerController` is overriding those, probably to return an internal child view controller. Looking at the view hierarchy in `viewDidAppear:`, there's certainly a child `PLImagePickerCameraView` and its likely there's a controller to go with it. Sadly we cannot override *this* controller.

Overriding those `childViewControllerFor...` methods, `preferredStatusBarStyle` and `prefersStatusBarHidden` do get called in-between `viewWillAppear:` and `viewDidAppear:`, and can indeed keep the status bar visible and `LightContent`. The **second interesting thing** though, is that before the `presentViewController` animation the status bar briefly blinks dark. No amount of extra calls to `setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate` in `viewWillAppear:` or other places such as `viewDidLoad:` seem to prevent that.

The **third interesting thing** is that the bar style is still getting set to dark during dismissal, and no extra calls to `setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate` in the picker's `viewWillDisappear:` or `viewDidDisappear:` seem to prevent that.

---

**tl;dr** -- I've found that overriding `UIImagePickerController` to hide & show the status bar on demand to work pretty well, but setting the bar style is problematic. Something in the picker class or `UINavigationController` itself is automatically preferring the `Default` bar style, and when its switched to that on dismissal, it seems difficult to switch it back.

I've seen the Question [UIImagePickerController breaks status bar appearance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880364), and nothing I've seen there has helped yet, and iOS8.1 doesn't fix it. I was sure that setting the picker's `navigationBar.barStyle` to black would do it, but no dice. Any ideas anybody?

(Also, any tips on preventing a `UINavigationController`'s navigation bar from sliding up to 44 height when the status bar is hidden would be useful thx)